# W3C Validator doesn't load the actual sources

Tags: wordpress, caching, w3c, w3c-validation, mod-expires

I wanted to use W3C validator to optimize my Wordpress blog. At the main page it claimed 28 errors. One of them for example was the following:

> Line 28, Column 53: end tag for "meta" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
>
> ```
>  <meta name="DC.Creator" content="Raffael Herrmann">
> ```

So I fixed it and clicked on revalidate. Nevertheless the validator says, that this error is still existent. But if I look at the browsers source code window from my webbrowser, I can see that may changes are delivered successful. If I check "Show Source" at the W3C validator options and reload my site, I can see, that the source code from my site, the validator uses, is outdated/without the changes.

So can anybody explain me why the W3C validator doesn't recognize my changes? If you wan't to have a look yourself - http://code-bude.net/ is the URL of my blog.

Comment: I see several "end tag omitted" errors, but none of them apply to the "meta" tag.  So you have fixed that one, and have only 24 more to clean up.  Good luck!

Comment: @DavidGorsline I've already fixed the end tag omitteds... The problem is, that the validator doesn't recognize my changes in realtime. At first I thought the mod_expires in my .htaccess would be the problem, but mod_expires doesn't cache html/php. An I can see the changes in my browser in realtime. So there is no caching. Nevertheless the w3c validator seems to cache my site and show/recognize the changes only every few hours. So how to let now w3c that I changed something on my site?

Comment: I am experiencing same issue at the moment - page is changed, but it seems like W3C validator is validating old version of page. Could it be that this service is using some proxy server which caches the page?

Comment: It seems to be an infrequent problem. A day later it recognized my changes instantly. But I hadn't changed any caching rules or things like that. Only the html output was changed by me. So I think it's some kind of bug in the W3C validator.

Comment: Belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is a little old, but I'm having the exact same issue right now, I found this thread, and then I found an easy workaround.

**The issue:**

I fixed some of the things the validator told me about, clicked the Revalidate button, and it shows the same errors and source code as it did before I made changes.

Some caching is definitely happening somewhere.  I'm using WordPress too, along with the W3TC plugin, but the only Browser cache setting I have enabled is Set Last-Modified header.

**The solution:**

I've ran into similar issues before with other services, and here is an easy workaround...

Add "?x=1" to the end of the url, increasing the value each time you want to re-validate.  This makes it skip the cache because it is a different url. (If you already have a question mark in the url, use "&x=1". If you already have "x=" in the url, use anything else, like "y=".)

**For example...**

If you want to validate the home page at:

`http://mydomain.com/`

...you can re-validate it at:

`http://mydomain.com/?x=1`

...and re-validate it again at:

`http://mydomain.com/?x=2`

...and so on.

If you want to validate a dynamic page at:

`http://mydomain.com/mypage.php?x=123`

...you can re-validate that page at:

`http://mydomain_com/mypage.php?x=123&y=1`

...and validate it again at:

`http://mydomain_com/mypage.php?x=123?y=2`

...and so on.